# How to restore /etc/ and its root permissions with rsync?

Tags: permissions, backup, rsync, nas

I backup my /etc/ on a NAS, with rsync -a, as user1 on the machine and user1  on the NAS. No root or sudo involved.
When rsync creates the files on the NAS, it gives ownership to user1, although /etc/ is owned by root on the machine. That's understandable.

But in case I want to restore later, how will I ensure that /etc/ comes back as root-owned and not user1-owned?
Is it the proper way to backup /etc/ ?

Comment: What about the `-p`-option to preserve permissions (see `man rsync`).

Comment: @mook765 it doesn't work because rsync will try to set root as owner of the files on the NAS, where rsync is logged as user1. Permission denied. In the end I decided to just pack everything into a tar (that keeps the permission inside it) and upload the tar, owned by user1. It doesn't allow incremental back up but otherwise it does the job quite well.